# How to host a angular web application on SharePoint

Tags: angular, sharepoint, hosting, sharepoint-online

I have developed a `angular web application`. I want to host that application on `SharePoint` so that at least people who are in the same org/network can browse my site with all the user interaction.

Angular project has `.html` and `.ts` file extension not `.aspx`.

My application getting data from reports which are there in `assets` folder of application and using `Bootstrap4.5, Angular 10`. I am using `SharePoint Online 2019 OnPrem` version.

Please suggest me possible solution

Answer (score 0):

is it SP Online or onPrem?

You may add an .aspx page to a library  (js and css to the same library) and in this page you may put all your html code and src your css and js BUT please be aware that any page will be always displayed 'under' the main SharePoint master page and you may receive some styling conflicts

Here is a nice article that present the concept I tried to explain

- https://dattabase.com/blog/classic-solution-in-modern

---

#### Update 1

In order to present some single page html app with any JS framework in SharePoint we need to:

1. make sure custom scripts is enabled on site were we want to store our solution

in order to do this we need to connect to SharePoint admin page using Management Shell (login as admin) and run the fallowing command

`Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`

More reference information about this may be found here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script

2. enable 'wiki page home page' feature in order to have site assets enabled on site

When being on site were we want to include our solution go to site features and enable wiki page home page feature.

Go to line `<SiteURL>/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx` and activate
[image]

3. update html file of our solution to aspx and prepare for SharePoint

lets say I have the fallowing files that create my solution (some html, some js, some css)
[image]

the **page.html** has the fallowing content

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<body>
        <!-- my html -->
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p id="world"></p>
</body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

the **script.js** has the fallowing content

```
document.getElementById("world").innerText = "world";
```

the **style.css** has the fallowing content

```
#world{
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

all we need to do is change the format from html to aspx file. So we update the **page.html** to **page.aspx**. Then we need to update the content to the fallowing

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<!-- Required to be used in an App Part -->
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />

<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false" />
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false" />
        
        <!-- my html -->
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p id="world"></p>
    </form>
</body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

4. add all needed file to site and test

next we need to go to `<SiteURL>/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx` and upload all the needed files to SharePoint (all style, scripts, views etc.)
[image]

after all is uploaded we may click on page.aspx to see the working result in browser
[image]

5. embed solution on SharePoint page

now in order to add this solution to any page we need to add embed webpart to page and paste the page.aspx url to the config
[image]

Comment: Hi, this SP is onPrem. regarding article link, Can I upload zip file and browse pages or do I need to upload actual code

Comment: Well you do need to add actual page to a page library an all the js and css files you need to add in  any other library and probably correct the src tag to get the code from new location. Yes you will need to add actual code in separate files

Comment: @R15 which on prem version you use? If 2016 or 2019 then it would be very similar to online so I could try to write some manual. At the moment I don't have access to any SP onPrem but only online. Also if you use 2016 or 2019 do you use modern UI or classic? If you have 2013 version or lower then you have only classic UI

Comment: Today I got time to check it. I am using SP online with version 2019. There is a button on top 'create site', this allows me create site with pages, those looks like MS slides. keep the text and controls but I am looking for adding Angular pages(.html & .ts).

Comment: I added the Update 1 to my answer ... fallowing those steps should be what you are looking for